# Excessive trading due to sharp cutoffs

Tags: portfolio-optimization, factor-models, transaction-costs

I am running a stock trading system based on traditional factors (value, momentum, etc). I generate a combined factor score for each stock on every day at the close, and at the open of the next day, I trade to hold positions in the top 30% absolute value scores (long the most positive 15%, and short the most negative 15%).

Currently, if a stock drops out of the top 30% strongest absolute scores, I liquidate the position. Then if it re-enters, I have to trade back into the whole position. The result is that there's a lot of trading activity around the 70th percentile:

[image: Stuttering around 70th percentile]

Is there a smarter way to do this?

Comment: How about not liquidating entirely but only selling proportional to how far you are from entering the top 30%? And likewise for buying.

Comment: There could be two thresholds instead of one. When a stock that you don't own has a score that is 30% or less you buy it, but for a stock you already own, you don't sell it until it is 40% or more. This gives you a 10% "buffer" area.